# using setInterval for keep scrolling in nightwatch js

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, nightwatch.js

i have a nightwatch js script that will run scrolling in my webpage
this is my custom commands script

```
'use strict'

exports.command = function (param) {
    this.execute(function (param) {
        $(window).scrollTop(param)
    }, [param])
}
```

and then from my testing file i call that scrolling script. this is my script

```
module.exports = {
    'Scrolling testing': function (client) {
        client.url('http://localhost:1200/').waitForElementVisible('div.user-item', 5000);
        let i = 50
        setInterval(function () {
            console.log(i)
            client.scrollTo(i)
            i += 50
        }, 500)
    }
};
```

i just wanna make scrolling action every 500ms with setInterval, but the browser just scroll only once (but the console log keep runing). can anyone solve this..

sorry for bad english :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a some options that I will do to get the behavior you want but I dont know which one will satisfy you:

1. Use `perform` ([See documentation here](http://nightwatchjs.org/api/perform.html))

`perform` command enables you to execute some code, it can be asynchronous so you can do something like the example # 1 (for some reason if I put the code below it wont be formatted)

2. Use `executeAsync` ([See documentation here](http://nightwatchjs.org/api/executeAsync.html)) instead of `execute`:

`execute` command runs synchronous, so maybe after the first execution it continues with the test and then it finishes. So instead, use `executeAsync`  and move the whole setInterval function inside it so you dont need the custom command (imho, I will delete it since doesnt do so much thing). See example # 2

**Example # 1**

```
client
    .url('http://localhost:1200/')
    .waitForElementVisible('div.user-item', 5000)
    .perform(function(client, done){
        let i = 50, maxExecutions = 10, intervalTime = 0;
        intervalTime = setInterval(function () {
            console.log(i);
            client.scrollTo(i);
            i += 50;
            maxExecutions++;
            if(maxExecutions===10) {
                clearInterval(intervalTime); //to prevent an infinite loop
                done();
            }
        }, 500)
    })
```

**Example # 2**

```
module.exports = {
    'Scrolling testing': function (client) {
        client
            .url('http://localhost:1200/')
            .waitForElementVisible('div.user-item', 5000)
            .executeAsync(function (param, done) {
                let i = 50, maxExecutions = 10, intervalTime = 0;
                intervalTime = setInterval(function () {
                    maxExecutions++;
                    console.log(i);//will be logged on browser console
                    $(window).scrollTop(param);
                    i += 50
                    if(maxExecutions===10){
                        clearInterval(intervalTime);
                        done(/*you can send some data here*/)
                    }
                }, 500)
            }, [], function(/*the data that you have send*/){
                //do something
            })
    }
};
```